# How to define call of stored procedure in hibernate mapping file and then call it from java (mssql server)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I need to call stored procedure in java code (`entityManager` is available only). This stored procedure should be defined in some `hbm.xml` file.

I didn't find any solution how to do it.

In hibernate documentation I found that it should be declared in this way.

```
<sql-query name="InsertTestCaseData" callable="true">
    { ? = call dbo.InsertTestCaseData(:ID) }
</sql-query>
```

This procedure returns only result code (`mssql server`). how should I describe it in mapping file? And how to handle if this procedure returns some value of some column, should I define  `<return-property>` in `hbm` file?

I have only `entityManager` object. there is no method like `getNamedQuery()`.

What method could be used instead?

And where mapping file should be located? Could it be separate file with queries only?

Answer (score 0):

There are few examples for you [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures)   but here is how you would call a stored procedure using entity

```
// This stored procedure returns a result set and has one input parameter.
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "ReadAddressById",
    resultClasses = Address.class,
    procedureName = "READ_ADDRESS",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=IN, name="P_ADDRESS_ID", type=Long.class)
    }
)
@Entity
public class Address {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my entity classes generated and I have to use separate mapping file to define queries